# What is the best way to setup SenderSubID in QuoteRequest Message?

Tags: quickfix

I am developing on quickfixj

Trying to set the SenderSubID Field in the header of QuoteRequest message.

I use the following code:

```
QuoteRequest msg = new QuoteRequest();
msg.getHeader().set(new SenderSubID(myid));
```

Is this the best way or is there any better way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.5.0/) online documentation for QuickfixJ. Will save you a lot of trouble.

The *Header* class which you return from *getHeader()* doesn't support a set function. But has 2 set functons which can work for you.

```
setString
```

More flexible, but you may add in fields which aren't supported in the FIX standards and which would get rejected from the client at a later stage.

```
setField
```

Safest way to create a message, would generate errors the moment you try to add a non existent field in a message. But this mayn't be a foolproof method, if you are playing around with xml file which QuickfixJ uses to check against fields present/not present in a message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `getHeader()` allows you to use `set()`. If it does, use it.
Otherwise simply use `setField()`.

`Message.set()` is most of the time the safest way to add new fields to messages, because the compiler prevents you from adding fields that are not a part of a certain MsgType (based on the FIX x.x specs).